# New to Swift programing. Struggling with integer rounding

Tags: swift3

I need to figure out a way to round an integer up to its nearest thousand and down to it's nearest thousand.  I've tries searching for solutions on here but they haven't seemed to work out for me.

The range of whole numbers will lye between 10000 and 18300.
If I give a value of 17350, I need a formula to round that value to 17000 and a formula to round up to 18000 so I can use those numbers in another formula.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func roundDownToNearestThousand(n: Int) -> Int {
    return (n/1000) * 1000
}

func roundUpToNearestThousand(n: Int) -> Int {
    if n % 1000 == 0 {
        return n
    } else {
        return (n/1000) * 1000 + 1000
    }
}
```

Of course, you can always modify and put these into an extension

Comment: This solution is only correct for positive values of `n`.